# Access restriction in caddy web server

Tags: access-control, caddy, caddyfile

My Caddyfile is pretty easy and looks like this:

```
:80
tls off
root /var/www
gzip
fastcgi / /var/run/php5-fpm.sock php
```

Is it possible to restrict access to `/var/www/secret`, so http://localhost/secret/secretfile.txt is no longer accessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either [basicauth](https://caddyserver.com/docs/basicauth) or [internal](https://caddyserver.com/docs/internal) to achieve this. Since you want a *secret* directory, internal would be my recommendation here.

---

**basicauth**

```
basicauth /secret username password
```

Still accessible, but protected with username/password.

**internal**

```
internal /secret
```

Not accessible, throws a 404 Not Found status.